# reading xml tags attributes

Tags: c#, xml

This is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmlns:util="http://" xmlns:tcas="http://" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:cas="http:/" xmlns:type10="http:///" xmlns:ne="http:///" xmlns:group3="http:///org/"  xmi:version="2.0">
    <cas:NULL xmi:id="0"/>
    <group1:Black xmi:id="19" code="1" ref="0" mask="23086" id="SIMPLE_Black"/>
    <group1:White xmi:id="25" code="2" ref="0" mask="21" WhiteNumber="0"/>
    <group1:White xmi:id="31" code="7" ref="23" mask="39" WhiteNumber="1"/>
    <group1:White xmi:id="37" code="3" ref="53" mask="68" WhiteNumber="2"/>
    <group1:White xmi:id="43" code="7" ref="71" mask="86" WhiteNumber="3"/>
    <group1:White xmi:id="49" code="3" ref="88" mask="102" WhiteNumber="4"/>
    <group2:Pink xmi:id="8745" code="4" ref="20613" mask="20614" other="5904"/>
    <group2:Pink xmi:id="8753" code="7" ref="20624" mask="20625" other="5907"/>
    <group2:Pink xmi:id="8761" code="5" ref="20625" mask="20626" other="5908"/>
    <group2:Pink xmi:id="8769" code="2" ref="20640" mask="20641" other="5911"/>
    <group2:Pink xmi:id="8777" code="1" ref="20641" mask="20642" other="5912"/>
    <group2:Pink xmi:id="8785" code="6" ref="20701" mask="20702" other="5923"/>
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31715" code="3" ref="6959" mask="6966" other="2457" />
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31727" code="5" ref="6967" mask="6971" other="2458" />
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31747" code="7" ref="6973" mask="6977" other="2460" />
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31759" code="2" ref="6978" mask="6981" other="2461" />
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31771" code="8" ref="6982" mask="6991" other="2463" />
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31783" code="8" ref="6992" mask="6993" other="2464" />
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31795" code="8" ref="6994" mask="7002" other="2465" />
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31807" code="9" ref="7003" mask="7013" other="2466" />
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31827" code="3" ref="7015" mask="7022" other="2468" />
    <group2:Blue xmi:id="31847" code="1" ref="7024" mask="7026" other="2470" />
    <group2:Red xmi:id="29184" code="2" ref="6100" mask="6101" other="2178" />
    <group2:Red xmi:id="29217" code="1" ref="6105" mask="6106" other="2182" />
    <group2:Red xmi:id="29234" code="4" ref="6109" mask="6110" other="2184" />
    <group2:Red xmi:id="29278" code="1" ref="6128" mask="6129" other="2188" />
    <group2:Yellow xmi:id="30300" code="4" ref="6398" mask="6400" other="2304" />
    <group2:Yellow xmi:id="30333" code="1" ref="6404" mask="6406" other="2308" />
    <group2:Yellow xmi:id="30394" code="5" ref="6426" mask="6429" other="2314" />
    <group2:Yellow xmi:id="30431" code="1" ref="6437" mask="6439" other="2318" />
    <group2:Yellow xmi:id="30468" code="6" ref="6447" mask="6450" other="2322" />
    <group2:Green xmi:id="79301" code="1" ref="2501" mask="2505" GreenType="NP"/>
    <group2:Green xmi:id="79306" code="6" ref="2505" mask="2506" GreenType="O"/>
    <group2:Green xmi:id="79311" code="1" ref="2507" mask="2520" GreenType="ADJP"/>
    <group2:Green xmi:id="79316" code="1" ref="2521" mask="2523" GreenType="PP"/>
    <group2:Green xmi:id="79321" code="1" ref="2524" mask="2542" GreenType="NP"/>
    <group3:Brown xmi:id="117792" code="7" ref="16421" mask="16426" id="0" max="0"/>
    <group3:Brown xmi:id="119483" code="1" ref="16486" mask="16497" id="0" />
    <group3:Brown xmi:id="117469" code="1" ref="16486" mask="16492" id="0" />
    <group3:Brown xmi:id="119364" code="8" ref="16493" mask="16497" id="0" />
    <group2:Grey xmi:id="137117" code="1" ref="143" mask="150" id="1" />
    <group2:Grey xmi:id="137131" code="1" ref="150" mask="151" id="2" />
    <group2:Grey xmi:id="137145" code="8" ref="152" mask="159" id="0"/>
    <group2:Grey xmi:id="137159" code="1" ref="152" mask="159" id="1" />
    <group3:Purple xmi:id="236545" id="0" category="R" argument="236523"/>
    <group3:Purple xmi:id="235624" id="0" category="A" argument="235612"/>
    <group3:Purple xmi:id="232638" id="0" category="A" argument="232632"/>
    <group3:Purple xmi:id="236845" id="0" category="A" argument="236821"/>
    <group3:Purple xmi:id="242015" id="0" category="C" argument="242003"/>
</xmi:XMI>
```

It is a list of colours and each colour has some attributes

I want to get few colors (White, Blue, Brown, Yellow)

and read its attributes and put it in a database

I managed to read one tag only and could not get its attributes

This is my code so far

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNodeList xmlnode;
        int i = 0;
        string str = null;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\Output\1.xmi", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        xmldoc.Load(fs);
        xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("group1:White");
        for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            str = xmlnode[i].Item("code").InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].Item("ref").InnerText.Trim() + "  " + xmlnode[i].Item("mask").InnerText.Trim();
            MessageBox.Show(str);
        }
```

I got xmlnode[i] correct but no attributes !

how to read tags attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, `group1` and `group2` are not declared in the posted Xml.

For the question **how to read tags attributes?**, you could access to attribute, by calling `.Attributes["AttributeName"]`, like :

```
....
xmlnode = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("group1:White");
for (i = 0; i <= xmlnode.Count - 1; i++)
{
    str = xmlnode[i].Attributes["code"].Value + "  " + xmlnode[i].Attributes["ref"].Value + "  " + xmlnode[i].Attributes["mask"].Value;
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
....
```

I hope you find this helpful.